# How to view a large one page pdf?

Tags: pdf

I've been able to compile a large one page PDF. Now I can't view it.

```
$ pdfinfo largefile.pdf 
Producer:       cairo 1.15.10 (http://cairographics.org)
CreationDate:   Fri Feb 28 23:36:40 2020 CET
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      1.67622e+06 x 764 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      5739024 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

I've tried

- mupdf
  `error: malloc of array (1019 x 8939852 bytes) failed`
  `mupdf: warning: Errors found on page. Page rendering may be incomplete.`
- qpdfview
  `Bogus memory allocation size`
- gv
  opens pop up window
  `Unrecoverable error: rangecheck in setscreen`
  `Operand stack:`
      `0.0180904  0  --nostringval--`
- okular
  opens a white page and is killed when trying to zoom in:
  `Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/128/"`
  `org.kde.okular.core: Running out of memory on page 0 (1837153x841 px);`
- evince
  very slow, cant zoom in. I haven't tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/51325352/3014199 but don't expect much from it.
- xpdf
  opens the PDF and displays the top left corner. However the cursor becomes an "hourglass" and navigation is impossible (nothing happens on key press)

I am looking for a way to view my large PDF. I am ok with watching it piecewise, e.g. `xpdf -initialX=100 -initialY=20` if only that exists.

Comment: **gimp** can show a huge `tif` picture downloaded from [this link](https://www.spacetelescope.org/images/heic1502a/). I downloaded and viewed the 1.7 GB version with 40000x12788 pixels (~ 511 million pixels), the second largest file. So maybe you can make a huge picture file instead of a pdf file.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a pdf file that's giving you trouble so we can test on our own? You might need to create one with dummy text if you can't share the one you're actually interested in (for copyright or similar reasons).